# Call function inside its Class

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I want to call a function on every instantiation of its class.
I have a class in my nodejs project which returns me the following error:

> /path/to/dir/myClass.js:11
>   myMethod();
>   __________^
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
>       at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
>       at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
>       at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)

**myClass:**

```
class myClass {
    constructor() {
        this.x = 1;
        this.y = 4;
    }

    myMethod() {
        console.log("I'm being used.");
    }

    myMethod();
}
```

When I call my function like this:

```
this.myMethod();
```

I get this error:

> Unexpected token .

Comment: you can't call ANYTHING where you are trying to do so - that's not how you write classes in javascript

Comment: You have to move the function call inside a method. You cannot put statements like that directly inside the class. If you want it to run at the time of instantiation, move it inside the constructor.

Comment: @912312381 Yes … it's `constructor` … like Chris just said.

Answer (score 3):

**Answer from Comments provided by @Chris G:**
Move function call up into constructor function.

```
class myClass {
    constructor() {
        this.x = 1;
        this.y = 4;
        this.myMethod();
   }

    myMethod() {
        console.log("I'm being used.");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call a function inside the other function. If you want to call `myMethod` then create a new function and call it inside that like below.

```
class myClass {
    constructor() {
        this.x = 1;
        this.y = 4;
    }

    myMethod() {
        console.log("I'm being used.");
    }

    myFoo = () => {
        this.myMethod()
        // Your code
    }
}
```